# PERMUTATIONS Olympiad Number Theory Question

Tags: permutations

AIMO 2020 Olympiad Permutation Question[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFWCH.png)

This question was encountered during a mathematics competition, and I thought that Induction on k would be a suitable method of solving it. Am I right?

Comment: There is a beautiful combinatorial proof ... see if you can dream it up ?

Comment: Is it possible to solve using Induction?

Comment: Or AM/GM Inequality

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{m!}{m^k(m-k)!}=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(m-k+1)}{m^k}=\prod_{k=0}^{k-1}\big(1-\frac{k}{m}\big)
$$
Similarly
$$
\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}=\prod_{k=0}^{k-1}\big(1-\frac{k}{n}\big)
$$
Since $m<k$ it follows that for all $k$:
$$
1-\frac{k}{m}<1-\frac{k}{n}
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{m!}{m^k(m-k)!}<\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}
$$

Comment: This is great! I was wondering if it is possible to answer using Induction?

Comment: Or AM/GM Inequality?

Comment: Would doing induction on just k work?

Comment: I don't think it easy to prove it by induction since you'll have to prove on each $k,m,n$ seperately.